# Регулярное выражение для BB тега

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть строка вида: `[text='15';]`
Нужно с помощью регулярного выражения и php вытащить число 15.

Comment: во-первых, это не BB, во-вторых, готовых парсеров ВВ - как грязию в третьих, кому нужно это ископаемое чудище в век маркдауна?

Comment: возможно там `size=15` имелось в виду

Comment: Да, именно это и должно быть

Comment: @vinchesteras1 отредактируйте вопрос тогда, чтобы не было путаницы

Comment: @Ипатьев, Вы как всегда любезны. MD подходит для простого форматирования, тогда как BB может больше (а если нужен большой функционал - выбор очевиден).

Comment: Быть может Вам поможет http://php.net/manual/ru/book.bbcode.php

Answer (score 1):

По скольку не совсем ясно, какое точно выражение вам нужно, то вот парочка:

```
$text = "[size=15] asdasd [text='15';]";

if(preg_match("/\[size=(?<size>\d+)\]/", $text, $matches)){
    print_r($matches); 
    //echo $matches['size'];
}

if(preg_match("/\[text='(\d+)';\]/", $text, $matches)){
    print_r($matches);
    //echo $matches[1];
}
```